# How do you make two cubes move at the same time without one lumping at the bottom?

Tags: animation, soft-body

I have two cubes, one is inside the other, and I have softbody enabled on both of them. The problem is, when I have them fall, the inner cube falls down and dies.

blend file: [here](https://pasteall.org/blend/0c554a7581c54a1aa926f4998570835a)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just check your stiffness checkbox for your inner cube.

Result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: what about the part that floats around in the middle cube? Because I want it to float in the center of the cube. Is there a way to set coords?

Comment: This was not your question. I answered your question. If you ask another question, please open a new question. Thank you.

Comment: you can do this by setting the "animated" flag with keyframes and then animate the coordinates via keyframes.